# Extract the type of expression with Resharper structural replace

Tags: c#, replace, resharper, ienumerable, structural-search

I am trying to make a R# structural search and replace to offer the following

```
foo.ToList()
```

should be converted to the below if the user selects the refactoring

```
foo as List<int> ?? foo.ToList()
```

so in R# I would try for the pattern

```
$expr$.ToList()
```

and for the replace

```
$expr$ as List<$type$> ?? $expr$.ToList()
```

however I can't figure out how I could assign `$type$` where

```
typeof($expr$) is IEnumerable<$type$>
```

In theorey it should work because I can constrain `$expr$` to be of type `IEnumerable<T>` but I don't have `$T$` available as a replace token.

Is this in way at all possible?